# How do i use ViewAccsessScope beans when testing in Arquillian?

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss-arquillian, codi

When i use @ViewAccsessScoped beans from CODI i get the following error, when using Arquillian for testing my beans.

org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException : WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped

is there anyway to get this to work?

//Trind

Comment: What protocol are you using for your test, Servlet, Local or something else? What is your app server?

Comment: Jboss 7.1 , Servlet 3.0

Comment: How is your test setup? Are you triggering the rendering of the page? This kind of makes sense if you're not triggering the rendering of a UI page.

Comment: No we are just accessing the bean directly. All other beans with diffrent scope than ViewAccessScoped are working however.

Comment: Right, ViewAccessedScope is dependent on someone rendering a JSF view, which doesn't happen here.

Comment: Is there any good way to mock it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to mock the FacesContext and got it working no idea if this is the best approch however.
I used Mockito to when doing the mocks.

```
    FacesContext mock = null;

    final Map<Object, Object> attributes = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    public void mockFacesContext() {

        if (mock == null) {
            mock = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);

            try {
                Method m = FacesContext.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setCurrentInstance", FacesContext.class);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(FacesContext.class, mock);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Mockito.when(mock.getAttributes()).thenReturn(attributes);

            ExternalContext ext = Mockito.mock(ExternalContext.class);
            Mockito.when(ext.getSession(false)).thenReturn(
                    Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class));

            Mockito.when(mock.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(ext);

            UIViewRoot uiViewRoot = Mockito.mock(UIViewRoot.class);
            Mockito.when(uiViewRoot.getViewId()).thenReturn("/test");
            Mockito.when(uiViewRoot.getLocale()).thenReturn(new Locale("se"));
            Mockito.when(mock.getViewRoot()).thenReturn(uiViewRoot);

            Application application = Mockito.mock(Application.class);
            Mockito.when(application.getSupportedLocales()).thenReturn(
                    Mockito.mock(Iterator.class));

            Mockito.when(mock.getApplication()).thenReturn(application);

        }
        return mock;
    }
```

Comment: For mocking you can simply use MyFaces-Test (even with Mojarra).

Answer (score 0):

You can check GroupedConversationContext#isActive to know if it's an issue with your setup or an issue with Arquillian. They just use the standard JSF API for doing the check.